# How to change Endpoint url structure of amazon s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, url, amazon-s3

I am trying to host a basic static website on s3 for some testing purpose
I am new to S3. 
I have few questions with URL structure of s3 buckets or endpoints.
i just created a bucket it gives me url like below

https://bucket-name.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/index.html

but i want url to be as follows

https://s3.Region.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/index.html

How can i do that?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use this format? Alternatively, you can use a normal domain name if you have one registered.

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd format is being deprecate. I recommend against using it.

See: [Amazon S3 Path Deprecation Plan – The Rest of the Story | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-path-deprecation-plan-the-rest-of-the-story/)

Comment: Yes i agree, but i want to use that for testing purpose..how can i change it to the later one?

Comment: Both formats are currently available. You can just use it. Please note there is a hyphen after `s3`, for example: `http://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/foo.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

The [path style format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html#path-style-access) you would like to use won't be available in near future for new buckets:

> Buckets created after September 30, 2020, will support only virtual hosted-style requests. Path-style requests will continue to be supported for buckets created on or before this date.

Thus it would be better to keep using virtual hosted-style, for the consistency reasons.

Comment: Yes i agree but for some testing purpose i want to get such link path style can you please explain how can i change that to later one?